# выбрать всех соавторов по годам?

Tags: sql

Задача про базу книг, где авторы могут быть авторами нескольких книг, а книги могут иметь несколько авторов. В базе три таблицы:

```
  books (bookID, bookTitle, bookAge);
  authors (authorID, authorName, authorAge);
  indexes (bookID, authorID)
```

Как выбрать всех соавторов Пупкина в книгах с 1960 по 1980 год?

Подскажите как действовать? Можно это одним запросом сделать?
Спасибо

Comment: Можете предоставить структуры таблиц?

Comment: этот тип связей таблиц имеет название "отношение многие ко многим"

Comment: что имеется в виду под структурой таблиц? я выше написал про три таблицы в базе: таблица indexes связывает таблицу с наименованиями книг books с таблицей с авторами authors, также в последних есть год издания книги (bookAge) и возраст автора (authorAge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без структуры и примера таблицы сложно понять, но попробуйте примерно так:

```
select distinct a2.authorName
from indexes i1 join indexes i2
         on i1.bookID = i2.bookID and i1.authorID <> i2.authorID
     join authors a1 on i1.authorID = a1.authorID
     join authors a2 on i2.authorID = a2.authorID
     join books b1 on i1.bookID = b1.bookID
where a1.authorName = 'Пупкин'
      and b1.bookAge >= 1960
      and b1.bookAge <= 1980
```

[Тест на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/409ddc/1/0).

Comment: спасибо, работает, но как база понимает псевдонимы до их определения? в первой строке "a2" уже используется в ссылке, хотя определяется только в пятой строке "join authors a2..."

Comment: @losew потому что сначала выполняется `from`, затем `where`, и только после этого `select`. [Подробнее тут](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html). Если вам был дан правильный ответ, не забудьте отметить его галкой напротив.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
    select * from indexes as i
    inner join authors as a using(authorID)
    inner join books as b using(bookID)
)
select distinct authorName from cte
where bookID in (
    select bookID from cte
    where authorName = "Пупкин"
    and bookAge >= 1960
    and bookAge <= 1980
)
and authorName <> "Пупкин";
```

Comment: прошу пояснить конструкцию "with cte as (..."

Comment: @losew известная конструкция, по которой [найти мануал можно за несколько секунд](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_common_table_expressions_cte.html).

Comment: @losew грубо говоря, конструкция with формирует таблицу с именем cte существующую в памяти до окончания выполнения запроса. Можно и без неё, но тогда join'ы пришлось бы делать дважды, в запросе и подзапросе.